# CSS for button with right triangle at lower right

Tags: css, sass

Looking to design this component.

[image]

Can someone provide me with css to create the above component

Width should determined by the length of the text it contains.

The cutin the lower right of the background color should be a right triangle with 8px sides.

I am trying with the below code, the triangle cut doesn't show up.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 24px;
  background: blue;
  color:white
}

.container:after{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
  border-left: 100px solid red;
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  Informational
</div>
```

Comment: This question doesn't show any effort, not even relevant scope like background color/structure/image to take into account.

Comment: `Can someone provide me with css to create the above component` This is not a code making site. You should show at least what you have tried to achieve this

Comment: a simple google search and you will get it

Comment: I am very basic at css, anyways thanks for you comments, I will try some implementation and get back.

Comment: Here are some nice snippets https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Answer (score 1):

Change color, height and width as per your requirement.

```css
div {
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}

div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0; right: 0;
  border-bottom: 80px solid white;
  border-left: 80px solid red;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="informational"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

content: ''; and box-sizing:border-box; display:inline-block; to display this.

Please check it here

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/techran/bpu9zwer/]
```

```css
.container {
background: #169ee9;
position: relative;
box-sizing:border-box;
display:inline-block;
padding:7px 15px;
color:#fff;
}

.container:before {
content: '';
position: absolute;
bottom: 0; right: 0;
border-bottom: 15px solid #000;
border-left: 15px solid transparent;
width: 0;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  Informational
</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like this will help but what do you think is the best practice, is it better to write this with CSS3 ?   Also I don't want to show the black color,  how can I make it transparent ?